# Twig json_encode with entity objects and collections (Symfony3)

Tags: javascript, json, object, twig, symfony

From my controller I pass an **array of entities** called `Tag` to the twig file like this:

```
return $this->render('tags/list.html.twig', array(
    'tags' => $tags,
));
```

Then, I show each tag in HTML with Twig `for`. Each `Tag` has a collection of entity `Texts` (in multiple languages). I want to pass the Texts collection to JS to do some treatments with jQuery.

```
{% for tag in tags %}
    {% if tag.texts|default %}
        <div data-tag-texts="{{ tag.texts|json_encode }}">...</div>
    {% endif %}

    ...
{% endfor %}
```

But it returns an empty object in JS : `Object {}` whereas my collection of Texts isn't empty. Usually, the Texts is an object of objects.

I tried a lot of things but with the same result :

```
{{ tag.texts|json_encode }}
{{ tag.texts|json_encode(constant('JSON_PRETTY_PRINT'))|raw }}
```

I would like to browse texts in order to show everyone in languages tabs. And all of this in a Boostrap Modal. So, I have to get the texts in javascript.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can implements the [\JsonSerializable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) interface to your object or use the  [JMSSerializerBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle)

Comment: I'm trying to test [the Symfony Serializer Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html)

Comment: hi @Felurian good choice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the idea of @Matteo, I installed the [Serializer Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) of Symfony (instead of implement the \JsonSerializable interface).

In my `Tag` entity, I added :

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;

public function serializer() {
    $encoder = new JsonEncoder();

    $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();
    $normalizer->setIgnoredAttributes(array(
        'typeCode', 'type', 'range',
        'useCaseCode', 'useCase', 'updatedAt', 'updatedBy'));

    $normalizer->setCircularReferenceHandler(function ($object) {
        return $object->getName();
    });

    $serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer), array($encoder));
    return $serializer->serialize($this, 'json');
}
```

Which is very useful because we can choose attributes and we have the entity relations.

In my Twig file :

```
<div data-tag="{{ tag.serializer }}">...</div>
```

In JS, I have my **Tag Object**. Texts are an **array of objects**. Everything is working great !

**Note** : Be careful of your Symfony's version. Mine was 3.0.9 and I couldn't install the Serializer Component. I had to update Symfony to 3.2 to make it work.

Comment: good answer @Felurian, to make this work for me, in my twig, i disabled the default escape filter by adding raw filter like this {{ Object.serializer|raw }} N.B : my symfony version is 2.6

Answer (score -2):

https://twigfiddle.com/ntexhi

Looks good with basic texts. I think you must have non UTF-8 characters which breaks your encoding and thus returns null JSON. Try to [`utf8_encode`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.utf8-encode.php) your data before sending it to Twig.

Comment: My database is already in utf8mb4_unicode_ci, but yes, I have accented characters... I don't want to encode each text of each tag, it will be a long process.

Comment: Well, did you tried what [@Matteo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41933455/twig-json-encode-with-entity-objects-and-collections-symfony3/41933637?noredirect=1#comment71047469_41933455)  suggested?

Comment: Yes, I'm testing right now [the Symfony Serializer Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html)